# scala functors taking arithmetic operators as argument

Tags: scala, functor

I would like to pass the arithmetic operators +, *, / into the Option monad.
I can do that for function `(Double,Double) => Double` like  `math.pow`

```
scala> def parseOp2(o1:Option[Double], o2:Option[Double], op: (Double,Double) => Double): Option[Double] =
     |     (o1,o2) match {
     |       case (Some(d1), Some(d2)) => Some(op(d1,d2))
     |       case _ => None
     |     }
parseOp2: (o1: Option[Double], o2: Option[Double], op: (Double, Double) => Double)Option[Double]

scala> parseOp2(Some(2),Some(3),math.pow)
res39: Option[Double] = Some(8.0)
```

But what is the signature of these operators. I tried

```
def parseOp2(o1:Option[Double], o2:Option[Double], op: Double => Double): Option[Double] =
  (o1,o2) match {
    case (Some(d1), Some(d2)) => Some(d1.op(d2))
    case _ => None
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The operators" themselves do not have a signature / type, because for example

```
+
```

is not a valid Scala expression.

The closest you can get is the following:

```
(_ :Double) + (_: Double)
```

This thing is indeed a valid scala expression, and its type is `(Double, Double) => Double`.

Furthermore, if you have a context from which the types can be inferred, then you can drop the explicit type ascriptions, as in the following example:

```
def foo(f: (Double, Double) => Double): Unit = println(f(42,3141595))
def foo(_ + _) // no "(_:Double)" necessary here
```

The type of the `_ + _` expression will be inferred automatically, it will again be `(Double, Double) => Double`. This, by the way, works for arbitrarily complex function literals, not just for operators. So, for example, if you define class `Foo` like this:

```
case class Foo(i: Int) { def bar(d: Double) = i / d }
```

then the strange construct `(_: Foo) bar (_: Double)`, which is a infix-form for `(_: Foo).bar(_: Double)` is a valid scala expression of type `(Foo, Double) => Double`:

```
scala> (_: Foo) bar (_: Double)
res4: (Foo, Double) => Double = $$Lambda$1335/591589887@3303e89e
```

I hope that answers your question and most of the potential modifications of your question.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot...and sorry for the live modifications !